# how to delete repeated images using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following images

```
<div id="test">
<img class='img1' />
<img class='img2' />
<img class='img3' />
<img class='img4' />
<img class='img1' />
<img class='img2' />
<img class='img3' />
<img class='img4' />
</div>
```

I want to remove images with class `img1, img2, img3, img4` which are repeated.

**Edit**

My second case is to remove images of first appeared images not from last of img4 but previous this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do:

```
$('#test').children().each(function(i, v){
    var $this = $(this), classname = $this.attr("class");
    $this.siblings('.' + classname).remove()
});
```

Demo :: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2ejb/)

Added:: do you mean something like this:

```
var classes = [];
$("img").each(function(id, vl) {
    $this = $(this), cls = $this.attr("class");

    if( $.inArray(cls, classes) < 0 ) {
        classes.push(cls);
    }
});
for(var c = 0; c < classes.length; c++ ) {
    if( $("img."+classes[c]).length > 1 ) {
        $("img."+classes[c]+":first").remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: @NavinRauniyar why would i vote down your question..? i didnt do it..!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove duplicates:

```
var seen = {};
$('img').each(function() {
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    if (seen[className])
        $(this).remove();
    else
        seen[className] = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var srcs = new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".img1").each(function() {
        if(jQuery.inArray( $(this).attr('src'), srcs ) != -1 ) {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            srcs.push($(this).attr('src'));
        }
    });
});
```